# Problems running unit tests after upgrading from Netbeans 6.5 to Netbeans 6.7

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, ant, junit

I am experiencing issues with existing projects from Netbeans 6.5 in Netbeans 6.7 when selecting a file under "Test Packages" and performing a right click-->Debug, or right click-->Run.  The error reported is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I am using JUnit 4.x

I have not changed any code since the upgrade and have tried this on multiple projects that were working and I still experience the problem.  I am able to perform right click-->Test on the entire project.

Are there any changes I would need to make due to the upgrade, or is anything broken in Netbeans 6.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work-around Solution Found**

If the following setting in Netbeans 6.7 is not checked, the tests work as they did in 6.5:
Right Click --> "Project Properties" --> "Build" --> "Compiling" --> "Compile on Save"

So, this is at least a work-around until real issue is understood.

-bn